# COUNTIF function if day of week is Tuesday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, countif, array-formulas

I need to count a column only if the corresponding cell in another column is a Tuesday.  An example image is:

[image: SO25561294 question example]

Initially, I was trying to use a COUNTIFS function paired with a WEEKDAY but I can't get it to work.

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B32,TRUE,A2:A32,WEEKDAY(3))
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B32,IF(A2=WEEKDAY(3),1,0))
```

Each unit needs to be counted on Tuesday every week.  If they count a day before or after it's considered late.  What needs to happen, is each unit needs to have a count of the number of days that they did count and then the number of days that they didn't count.  In the past, I have accomplished this last part by a simple arithmetic formula based on the number of days in the month.  In addition to the two counts, I also need any missed cells to be filled in with a red background.

The actual sheet has several tables in the same format ranging from 1 column to 65 columns.

Comment: You're quite clear about the "Counted" days, but not about the "Not Counted" days. I can't get my head wrapped around your description. And I'm not sure what a missed day means.

Comment: @pnuts - So "Not Counted" and "Missed" are the same thing??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try, in B34:

```
=SUM((WEEKDAY($A2:$A32)=3)*(B2:B32<>""))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied across to D34.

I am assuming you are able to count the number of Tuesdays in the relevant month and complete Row35 by deducting from that number the value in the cell immediately above.

Afterthought:

You have also what is really a completely separate question in your post (the red background) which I think is best handled with conditional formatting. Select B:D and in Conditional Formatting, New Rule... select Use a formula to determine which cells to format and under Format values where this formula is true: enter:

```
=AND(WEEKDAY($A1)=3,B1="")
```

Click Format..., select Fill and red, OK, OK.

Comment: I was just about to post a very similar answer. Nice. My formula was `{=SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(R2C1:R32C1)<>3,1,0)*IF(R2C:R32C<>"",1,0))}` or `{=SUM(IF(WEEKDAY($A$2:$A$32)=3,1,0)*IF(B$2:B$32<>"",1,0))}`.

Comment: How can the formula be edited to account for months that may not be 31 days- meaning the range will not be (B2:B32)? I have been able to adjust the first part of the formula to account for that but I can't figure out the 2nd part.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an column B and fill it with the following formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=3,1,"")
=IF(WEEKDAY(A3)=3,1,"")
...
```

Then you can count them with the following formulas:

```
Days counted       =COUNTIFS(C$2:C$32,">0",$B$2:$B$32,1)
Days not counted   =COUNTIFS(C$2:C$32,"",$B$2:$B$32,1)
```

You can hide the column B if you wish.